# Qt - setText() crahses program

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to get some text input for the user for further use. For this, I used a QInputDialog:

```
bool ok;
QString text = QInputDialog::getText(this, tr("QInputDialog::getText()"),
                                     tr("Your input:"), QLineEdit::Normal,
                                     QDir::home().dirName(), &ok);
if (ok && !text.isEmpty()) {
    textLabel->setText(text);
}
```

This crahses my program at the line `textLabel->setText(text);`. If I comment it out, it does not crash, but the `text` variable stays empty. What am I missing?
Thank you!

Comment: Is textLabel a nullptr?

Comment: What about "ui->textLabel->setText(text);"

Comment: I defined it in the .h file as `QLabel* textLabel;` and is not used before. I guess it is. Should it be?

Comment: I don't have any `ui` defined...

Comment: Did you initialize textLabel?

Comment: Something like "textLabel= new QLabel('some text');" or pass the reference to an existing QLabel.

Comment: Oh, stupid me! That was it. Now it does not crash. Thank you!

Comment: Great, may I post it as an answer and you accept it? if you belive that it was the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should initialize textLabel or give it a reference to an existing QLabel.

You can initialize it like this:

```
textLabel= new QLabel('some text');
```

Also, see [QLabel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#QLabel) documentation for more information on QLabel constructors.